# How to disable Widget Gutenberg Blocks?

Tags: widgets, block-editor

I was looking for how to deactivate the widget blocks that appeared with version 5.8 of Wordpress and I couldn't find it here. As I found the answer elsewhere, I share it here.

So, to disable widget blocks, just add this to your [child theme's](https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-child-theme/) functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'gutenberg_use_widgets_block_editor', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'use_widgets_block_editor', '__return_false' );
```

If you don't use (or don't want to use) a child theme, you can install this plugin :
https://wordpress.org/plugins/restore-classic-widgets/

Hope it helps.